# Make f1-12 keys work as standard function keys on Macbook Pro 5,3

Tags: 15.04, macbook-pro, function-keys

I'm using Ubuntu 15.04.

I'd like to have f1-12 work like f1-12 without holding fn, rather than volume and brightness.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppleKeyboard#Change_Function_Key_behavior) worked for me on MBA.

Here's another sentence to make it 30 characters.  I'll remove this if I think of anything else to add.